# SQL query to add missing values per id/date

Tags: sql

I have two tables, a table with id, date, value and a table with all the dates of interest.  I'd like to do a SQL query such that I get a new table exactly the same as my first table but not with NULL values per ID when a date is not present for a given ID.

Table 1.

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 8 |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 6 |

Table 2.

| date |
| --- |
| 2020-12-01 |
| 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-04-01 |
| 2021-05-01 |

After I "merge" the two tables the result would be:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-01 | NULL |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-02-01 | 8 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 | NULL |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2020-12-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-02-01 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 6 |
| 2 | 2021-05-01 | NULL |

Which SQL query do I need to run to get such result?

Comment: Do you have a table listing all the ids (users?) that need to appear in table1? Do all ids need to appear for all dates in table 2, or can different ids have different first and last date?  Which DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc, all have slightly different insert and merge syntax.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks!! no, ids are just in table1.  yes, all ids need to appear for all dates in table2 with same start and end date.  I am using postgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  d.date,
  t.value
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table1
)
  u
CROSS JOIN
  table2   d
LEFT JOIN
  table1   t
    ON  t.id   = u.id
    AND t.date = d.date
```

Though, I'd refrain from using `date` and other potential keywords as column names.